# SSL with Firebase hosting - OVH domain

Tags: angular, firebase, ssl, dns, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to set up my Angular app with a new domain bertrand-verdun.com bought on OVH, hosted on firebase hosting. The domain works but shows that it's insecure (no HTTPS, therefore no SSL).

I set up the domain on OVH by adding the A and TXT DNS in the DNSzone. It seems that the propagation is done, but firebase still gives me the message "Configuration Required" on the domain name in my firebase console.

I'm new to that, so I dont know what to do. Does my app needs some code to be certified ? Do I need to manually certify my website ? I can provide you more information if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have correctly done the three Steps described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain), you just need to wait a little bit.

As explained in this [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#ssl-provisioning) of the doc:

> After we verify domain ownership, we provision an SSL certificate for
>   your domain and deploy it across our global CDN **within 24 hours** after
>   you point your DNS A records to Firebase Hosting.
>
> ...
>
> While the domain is provisioning, you might see an invalid certificate
>   that does not include your domain name. This is a normal part of the
>   process and will resolve after your domain's certificate is available.

In most cases, it is faster than 24 hours.

Comment: I deleted all the A and TXT DSN relied to my domain, and created them again and It works perfectly about 4 hours later. Seems an error occurred the first time I when thought this process. Thank you !